# Amazon EC2 and RDS - Creating Access

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I was wondering how I can automatically enable access to my RDS server from my EC2 server. I have read that you can do this using keys kept on the EC2 server but I would rather not go that route. Instead I am assuming there is some kind of bankend security setting I can apply to my RDS to allow access from my EC2.

If anyone has done this before and can help, I would really appreciate it.

Regards,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Amazon's [DB security group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html) mechanism to control network access to the RDS instance. You'd place the RDS instance in a DB security group, the EC2 instances in an EC2 security group, and allow access to the DB security group from the EC2 security group.

Personally I would still use keys/passwords in addition to this however.